What scale is between minor and Major in quality?
I remember learning something about this in regular Music Education class, (not in Music Theory class), when I was in Elementary School. I don’t remember what grade I learned it in, but it was definitely sometime between Kindergarten and 6th Grade. The Music Teacher was teaching us this particular scale, but I forget now what it was called, and she was saying all Major Scales and all minor Scales are built from this scale because this scale was neither Major nor minor in quality, but it was also still a scale that was able to be played on an ordinary 12-key Piano tuned in 12-Tone Equal Temperament. Does anyone know what this scale is called? I don’t think it was the Solfège Scale, but I could be wrong. It definitely was not the C Major Scale, though, because that is a Major Scale, and it is also not between Major and minor in quality. The Music Teacher did, in fact, say that the scale I am asking about in this question is, in fact, between Major and minor in quality. I wish I remembered what she was calling that specific scale.
UPDATE: Just as Natural is between Flat and Sharp, the scale I am asking about is the BASIS for ALL minor Scales AND Major Scales.

If it could be played on the piano it is likely on this page  https://ianring.com/musictheory/scales/

An elementary music teacher talked to you about 12 tone equal temperament?

The basis for major/minor scales is the diatonic tuning system, not a scale.

@MichaelCurtis I'm not finding that strange. That's the only tuning our elementary teachers talked about to us, too. Since they didn't talk about any other tunings, they didn't mention the term, but they sure talked about it.

@Divizna, how did they talk about without naming it? That seems strange. My kid's music program has nothing about tuning systems.

@Aaron, my first thought was "diatonic scale" and the OP's memory is mixing things up.

@MichaelCurtis They talked about how it works - an octave is double the frequency, each semitone is the same ratio of frequencies, chamber A is set at 440 Hz. They never mentioned there are other tuning systems where a semitone isn't always the same ratio and Gb might not be the same sound as F#.

Note about your update: the relation between natural, flat and sharp is not the same kind of relation between major and minor. Fundamentally speaking, and at least in the context of "Western music", the flat/natural/sharp context is similar to integer (-1, 0, +1) while major/minor is more of a boolean context (true or false), but reality is much more complex: technically, a scale could be major, minor, both (see the blues scale) or none of them (eg. the chromatic scale). While those aspects could be related, they can not be considered as conceptually similar.

Following on @musicamante's comment, the major and minor scales get their names from the fact that their third degrees are a major and minor third above the tonic, respectively.  There is no third that is between the two (in the context of traditional European music theory, that is).  (The major and minor third in turn got their names from the fact that one is bigger than the other, but there's no "medium sized" third.)

There are a few scales that might fit the description of being "between" major an minor. For example, the Dorian mode shared its 3rd and 7th notes with minor, but its sixth note with major. The ascending melodic minor scale has the minor third, but the sixth and seventh of major.
However, given the age of the students involved, the most likely candidate is the chromatic scale, which comprises every pitch within an octave. It contains every possible scale in the 12-tone equal tempered system, so in that sense might be considered "between" every scale — especially if describing it to elementary school kids.

Chromatic was my first thought,  but any scale played on a 12 note piano? All except one of those scales will be short of notes before the scale reaches its octave!

@Tim '12 note piano' - well, I think we know what he really meant!   Not sure 'between' was a very precise choice of term either.

I'm not going to post an answer because it would basically be this, but 1) might be nice to lead with chromatic since that's the only one that explains the "all scales are built from this one" clue, and 2) for an "in between" mode it might be nice to mention Mixolydian ("starts like major, ends like minor") too.

Although "chromatic" is the least interesting of the possible answers, it is almost certainly the one OP's teacher meant.  Especially when you consider "all major scales" and "all minor scales" probably means "the Ionian and Aeolian mode in any of the 12 keys."

Especially since most children often sing out-of-tune, (causing some, most, or sometimes even all, of the sung Musical Pitches to be at least slightly out-of-tune; thereby, producing a scale in-between a minor Scale and a Major Scale; for example, if children, (especially in Grades K–3), sing the Solfège Scale in the Key of C, chances are they will sing Mi, La and Ti either too Flat or too Sharp, sometimes causing the scale to sound in-between minor and Major in quality), but also since the Solfège Scale is one of the scales that are used to teach children to sing and to distinguish different Musical Pitches, I think the scale I’m looking for might just be the Solfège Scale, (both ascending and descending): (Do—Re—Mi—Fa—Sol—La—Ti—Do and Do—Ti—La—Sol—Fa—Mi—Re—Do).

But neutral thirds, sixths, and sevenths won't be playable on a standard piano.

I didn't downvote, but this answer doesn't even make sense with the question. A scale based on children's out of tune singing, playable on piano?!? Solfege Scale which is clearly a major scale. Sure, you can get the relative minor from that, but that ins't between major and minor.

Maybe the Harmonic Minor scale, in its ascending version. That's a major scale with just one note changed, the 3rd.
On a more basic level, all scales are selected from the chromatic scale.  But, in the terms of your question, I wouldn't say that made it 'between' major and minor any more than a pile of bricks is 'between' two different styles of house.
But maybe 'between' isn't quite what you meant?   Any more than you meant 'an ordinary 12-key Piano' quite literally!


What scale is between minor and Major in quality?

Unfortunately, whatever you remember of what the teacher said it isn't enough to give a definitive answer, to either give a single answer, or somehow deduce what the teacher said.
It could be the chromatic scale.
It could be the diatonic scale/gamut.
Just about any collection of pitches will be called a scale be someone. The scale degrees ^1 ^2 ^4 ^5, which are the common degrees between all major and minor key scales, is defined as scale 165 genus primum at: https://ianring.com/musictheory/scales/165. (Most of what I find online about that "scale" just loops back to Ian Ring.)
Other ideas could be proposed.
Whatever the original idea was, my basic sense is it is not a good conception of the major/minor system of keys. The unity between major and minor in that system is the tonal scale degrees and the varying qualities come from the modal degrees. The system is based on a clear distinction of major and minor quality of thirds of either scales or chords.
You can find certain ambiguities in that system, such as minor seventh chords which are a kind of superimposing of minor and major triads. But that isn't "in between" major and minor. Certain chords like a dominant seventh sharp ninth chromatically augment the diatonic palette, but that also isn't between major and minor. Not in the sense of some prototype tonality from which is generated major and minor keys.
I'll go out on a limb and say there is not such an "in between major and minor" scale, and the original idea seems dubious.

The question is somewhat nebulous, but reading between the lines, if it's not referencing the chromatic scale, which indeed is neither major nor minor,(or could be construed as both...), the whole tone scale could be the next candidate, although why anyone would introduce kids (how old are 6th grade?) to it is a mystery.

I don't know why anyone would introduce children to it, but I do distinctly remember that the whole tone scale was mentioned to us sometime at that age (in the standard school class for everyone), too. That, and the pentatonic, were examples of non-diatonic scales. I'm skeptical to the claim that it's "between major and minor", though. After all you can clearly find the major third in a whole tone scale.

@Divizna - how about the half/whole tone, or its partner, whole/half tone scale then? Useful to know at 6yo..!

I don't recall any mention of those. And it wasn't at 6yo. I think it was sometime in 4th or 5th grade. So I was 9 or 10. If you're asking how old 6th-graders are, in my part of the world they're usually 12 by the end of the school year (a few will be just short of their 12th birthday and a few may be 13 already).

@Divizna - thanks, but just referring to '6th grade' is pretty meaningless to the rest of the world - could mean a variety of ages. Why do you think your 6th grade is the same as OP's?

I don't think it's necessarily strictly the exactly same. It may vary a little but I just don't expect it to differ by more than a year. 6th-graders are definitely not 6yo unless they started first grade as one-year-old toddlers. And the asker even mentions kindergarten before that. So if they say "kindergarten to 6th grade", then I read "okay so about 3 to 12, well probably not 3 but more like 5" and I assume that's a good enough approximation of the interval even if I don't know if their country places the cutoff for starting first grade precisely at "six by the 31st of August".

I mentioned whole tone scales to middle schoolers (12-14-yr-olds) once when I taught a broad music appreciation class and did one day on Impressionism. Talked about how, since all the steps were equal, it gives a (tonally) "disorienting" feeling of floating in a space without up or down, with no "home base."

Reading your question before the update, I was thinking of the Dorian scale, due to its inclusion of the major sixth interval. However, taking into your account that this scale is the basis of all major and minor scales, I second musiklanger regarding the pentatonic scale.
While I disagree that this scale is neither minor or major (as it specifically has major and minor modes, both of which contain a third/flat third respectively), I feel like one could make a strong justification for all diatonic modes being built from this scale, considering it is a subset of them.
Some people might also be confused by the fact that it sounds consonant to play both a minor and major pentatonic scale over a 12-bar blues, which is a unique characteristic of the pentatonic scale. In fact, the minor pentatonic scale, and the associated blues scale, are somewhat unique in that in some contexts it is consonant to improvise with them over a major chord progression.
But, I disagree with the statement that it is neither major or minor - however I can understand that a teacher may explain it like this. I would agree that the diatonic scales are built from it.
So while I don't think that your teacher described it well (if they were referring to the pentatonic), I do feel like this is the most likely scale. Especially considering that they were teaching elementary students, and the pentatonic is such an important scale to know about.
Peoples' ears naturally gravitate to the pentatonic, as is demonstrated by Bobby McFerrin in this Youtube video: 

 . This scale is widely used in melodies and improvisation, and sounds very pleasing to the ear.

The part where you say "she was saying all Major Scales and all minor Scales are built from this scale" makes me think it was the chromatic scale - the scale that comprises all 12 semitones.
I wouldn't say it's "between" major and minor, though. That's a very weird take on it, IMO. "Kind of both major and minor" would be more like it, if you wanted to classify it in this way at all.

I wonder why noone mentioned the "pentatonic scale" with the intervals of the black keys. Without a major or minor third (if it is possible to take the hiatus? "third" as the fourth actually) and without a leading tone either, you cannot hear major and minor quality, but by adding those you decide the quality. Mixolydian (M3, b7) and harmonic minor (m3, 7) would be possible, too.
In the scope of this question at least, I could argue that it does not make much of a difference if a (chromatic) scale includes both thirds and sevenths, or none as the pentatonic scale does – both are reluctant of decision, do not provide information about minor or major.

Can't speak for others, but I didn't mention pentatonic because I don't think it's what the asker is looking for. Simple as that. I'd also like to contest the idea that pentatonic isn't major or minor. The most common modes of it are even called the major pentatonic and minor pentatonic scale. Major pentatonic contains the major third just fine and as its third degree too; minor pentatonic contains the minor third as its second degree. And leading tone is hardly a requirement when the natural minor scale doesn't have it either.

Given the standard pentatonic scales are usually called "major" and "minor" pentatonic scales, this doesn't seem to fit the question.

Mea culpa, mistook pentatonic and black key playing (c#, d#, f#, g#, a# or on the white keys c, d, f, g, a and so forth). then I missed the right term for the specific pentatonic scale represented by the intervals of the black keys.

I agree with other commenters that the pentatonic scale is probably not what OP is looking for, but I do think it fits the "neither major nor minor" criterion if you use the rotation known variously as "neutral pentatonic", "Dorian pentatonic", "suspended pentatonic", etc.  (In D, it goes D-E-G-A-C.  I personally like the name supposedly given in Egyptian music, "Meh".)

The pentatonic scale is actually, like the major and natural minors, in two distinct flavours , yes, major and minor, depending where the root is. So this answer isn't right.

what is the major or minor third if the root is C# and the steps D#, F#, G# and A#? I've had this scale (R-2-3-2-2[-3]HT) in mind when posting. My mistake was to call it pentatonic, a term that by some standard suggests different intervals that indeed contain a third of a sort. I don't quite understand why its worth down-voting but it is okay. If you play black keys only there are no wrong tones, everything sounds harmonic, yet somewhat boring, it sounds to me like chinese music, too. Nothing I think them pianists would not know, though.

@musiklanger Also known as the F#6/9 chord.
